# SQL Server 2008 - Creating a Table based on field specs in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a source table that contains data for creating a table that looks like the following:

```
FIELD_POSITION   FIELD_NAME    FIELD_TYPE    FIELD_SIZE
-----------------------------------------------------------
1                FIELD1        TEXT          25
2                FIELD2        NUMERIC       0
3                FIELD3        TEXT          50
4                FIELD4        TEXT          15
5                FIELD5        NUMERIC       0
etc...
```

If the FIELD_TYPE in the source table is TEXT, then I want to create a field in my new target table as VARCHAR(FIELD_SIZE).

If the FIELD TYPE in the source table is NUMERIC, then I want to create a field in my new target table as NUMERIC(20,6) or DECIMAL(20,6)

My new target table would look like this (and have the data types described above):

```
FIELD1    FIELD2   FIELD3   FIELD4   FIELD5   Etc........
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way for me to query my source table and construct a CREATE TABLE statement to accomplish this?

I am new to SQL Server and have been learning different techniques using a copy of SQL Server 2008 Express that I have access to.

Thank You.

Comment: what is your problem? :(

Comment: I need help with the SQL statements to query the source table and create the target table.

Comment: This has many red flags all over it. Why do you need to use sql to query a table to build a statement to create a table? This has bad design written all over it. The only way you can do something like this is with dynamic sql.

Comment: OK.  I will pursue a solution other than SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some dynamic sql it is possible.

```
Declare @Table table (Field_Postion int,Field_Name varchar(50),Field_Type varchar(50),Field_Size int)
Insert Into @Table values
(1,'FIELD1','TEXT',25),
(2,'FIELD2','NUMERIC',0),
(3,'FIELD3','TEXT',50),
(4,'FIELD4','TEXT',15),
(5,'FIELD5','NUMERIC',0)

Declare @NewTableName varchar(50) = '[dbo].[SomeTableName]',@SQL varchar(max)

Select @SQL =coalesce(@SQL,'zzz') + +',['+Field_Name+'] '+case when Field_Type ='TEXT' then 'varchar('+cast(Field_Size as varchar(25)) +') ' else 'numeric(18, '+cast(Field_Size as varchar(25))+') ' end
 From @Table
 Order By Field_Postion

Select Replace(@SQL,'zzz,','Create Table '+@NewTableName+'(')+') ON [PRIMARY]'
--Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

```
Create Table [dbo].[SomeTableName]([FIELD1] varchar(25) ,[FIELD2] numeric(18, 0) ,[FIELD3] varchar(50) ,[FIELD4] varchar(15) ,[FIELD5] numeric(18, 0) ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If you are comfortable with the results, you can remove the comments from Exec()

Comment: Thank You John.  Your response and example sent me down a path of researching Coalesce and PIVOT.  Since I am a beginner, I will most likely implement a solution outside of (dynamic) SQL.  This was my first question posed on SO.  Hoping to learn how to do a better job at asking for assistance.  I truly appreciate the time you took to respond.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words.  For the record, your question was fine.  In Visual FoxPro, there was a CREATE FROM command which did exactly what you were looking for.   Nothing new under the sun

Comment: John - I am coming from the VFP (Free Table) environment.  I was surprised to see a -2 rating on my question as I did spend a fair amount of time trying to find a solution before I asked for help.  I also read/re-read my question multiple times before posting.  Lots to learn, I guess.  Thanks again!